# return values Error in a function swift 3

Tags: swift

I have an error when declaring the OperationQueue returned values in the function.

```
func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double?, rpmRuota wheelRpm: Double?, rpmPedali crankRpm: Double?) {
    accumulatedDistance? += distance ?? 0
    let distanceText = (accumulatedDistance != nil && accumulatedDistance! >= 1.0) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: accumulatedDistance!) : "N/A"
    let speedText = (speed != nil) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromValue: speed!*3.6, unit: .kilometer) + NSLocalizedString("/h", comment:"(km) Per hour") : "N/A"
    let cadenceText = (cadence != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  cadence!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

    let rpmPedaliText = (crankRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  crankRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"
    let rpmRuotaText = (wheelRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  wheelRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in
        self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, crankRpm: rpmPedaliText, wheelRpm: rpmRuotaText)
    }
}
```

> Incorrect argument in call (have'_:cadence:distance:crankRpm:wheelRpm:' expected:cadence:distance:rpmRuota:rpmPedali:')

The fix will pair crankRpm with rpmRuota (which means rpmWheel in Italian) and wheelRpm with rpmPedali (which means rpmCrank in Italian)..
leaving it like this:

```
func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double?, rpmRuota wheelRpm: Double?, rpmPedali crankRpm: Double?) {
    accumulatedDistance? += distance ?? 0
    let distanceText = (accumulatedDistance != nil && accumulatedDistance! >= 1.0) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: accumulatedDistance!) : "N/A"
    let speedText = (speed != nil) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromValue: speed!*3.6, unit: .kilometer) + NSLocalizedString("/h", comment:"(km) Per hour") : "N/A"
    let cadenceText = (cadence != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  cadence!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

    let rpmPedaliText = (crankRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  crankRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"
    let rpmRuotaText = (wheelRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  wheelRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in
        self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, rpmRuota: rpmPedaliText, rpmPedali: rpmRuotaText)
    }
}
```

Any idea of why? The pairing should be wheel to ruota and crank to pedal.

Can you see any misconnection of values inside the function's body?

```
      #UPDATE data flow
```

in Measurement.swift:

```
func valuesForPreviousMeasurement( _ previousSample:Measurement? ) -> ( cadenceinRPM:Double?, distanceinMeters:Double?, speedInMetersPerSecond:Double?, wheelRpm: Double?, crankRpm: Double?)? {


        var distance:Double?, cadence:Double?, speed:Double?, wheelCadence: Double?, cadenza:Double?
        guard let previousSample = previousSample else {
            return nil
        }
        if ( hasWheel && previousSample.hasWheel ) {
            let wheelTimeDiff = timeIntervalForCurrentSample(lastWheelEventTime, previous: previousSample.lastWheelEventTime)
            let valueDiff = valueDiffForCurrentSample(cumulativeWheel, previous: previousSample.cumulativeWheel, max: UInt32.max)


            distance = Double( valueDiff * wheelSize) / 1000.0 // distance in meters
            wheelCadence = (wheelTimeDiff == 0) ? 0 : Double(60.0 * Double(valueDiff) / wheelTimeDiff) // rpm make valueDiff as Double
            if  distance != nil  &&  wheelTimeDiff > 0 {
                speed = (wheelTimeDiff == 0 ) ? 0 : distance! / wheelTimeDiff // m/s

//                wheelCadence = (wheelTimeDiff == 0) ? 0 : Double(60.0 * valueDiff / wheelTimeDiff) // rpm
            }
        }

        if( hasCrank && previousSample.hasCrank ) {
            let crankDiffTime = timeIntervalForCurrentSample(lastCrankEventTime, previous: previousSample.lastCrankEventTime)
            let valueDiff = Double(valueDiffForCurrentSample(cumulativeCrank, previous: previousSample.cumulativeCrank, max: UInt16.max))

            cadenza = (crankDiffTime == 0) ? 0 : Double(60.0 * valueDiff / crankDiffTime) // RPM
            cadence = (crankDiffTime == 0) ? 0 : Double(60.0 * valueDiff / crankDiffTime) // RPM
        }
        print( "Cadence: \(String(describing: cadence)) RPM. Distance: \(String(describing: distance)) meters. Speed: \(String(describing: speed)) Km/h" )
        return ( cadenceinRPM:cadence, distanceinMeters:distance, speedInMetersPerSecond:speed, wheelRpm: wheelCadence, crankRpm: cadenza)
    }

    var debugDescription:String {
        get {
            return "Wheel Revs: \(cumulativeWheel). Last wheel event time: \(lastWheelEventTime). Crank Revs: \(cumulativeCrank). Last Crank event time: \(lastCrankEventTime)"
        }
    }
```

in sensor.swift:

```
protocol CadenceSensorDelegate {

    func errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(_ error:NSError)
    func sensorReady()
    func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double?,rpmRuota: Double?, rpmPedali: Double? )
}

class CadenceSensor: NSObject {

    let peripheral:CBPeripheral
    var sensorDelegate:CadenceSensorDelegate?
    var measurementCharasteristic:CBCharacteristic?
    var lastMeasurement:Measurement?
    let wheelCircunference:UInt32


    init(peripheral:CBPeripheral , wheel:UInt32=BTConstants.DefaultWheelSize) {
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        wheelCircunference = wheel
    }

    func start() {
        self.peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        self.peripheral.delegate = self
    }


    func stop() {
        if let measurementCharasteristic = measurementCharasteristic {
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: measurementCharasteristic)
        }

    }

    func handleValueData( _ data:Data ) {

        let measurement = Measurement(data: data, wheelSize: wheelCircunference)
        print("\(measurement)")

        let values = measurement.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(lastMeasurement)
        lastMeasurement = measurement

        sensorDelegate?.sensorUpdatedValues(speedInMetersPerSecond: values?.speedInMetersPerSecond, cadenceInRpm: values?.cadenceinRPM, distanceInMeters: values?.distanceinMeters, rpmRuota: values?.wheelRpm, rpmPedali: values?.crankRpm)
    }
}
```

in MainViewController : the error

```
func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double?, rpmRuota wheelRpm: Double?, rpmPedali crankRpm: Double?) {

        accumulatedDistance? += distance ?? 0
        let distanceText = (accumulatedDistance != nil && accumulatedDistance! >= 1.0) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: accumulatedDistance!) : "N/A"
        let speedText = (speed != nil) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromValue: speed!*3.6, unit: .kilometer) + NSLocalizedString("/h", comment:"(km) Per hour") : "N/A"
        let cadenceText = (cadence != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  cadence!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

        let rpmPedaliText = (crankRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  crankRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"
        let rpmRuotaText = (wheelRpm != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  wheelRpm!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in

            self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, crankRpm: rpmPedaliText, wheelRpm: rpmRuotaText)
        }
    }
```

in infoSpeedoViewController:

```
 func showMeasurementWithSpeed( _ speed:String, cadence:String, distance:String, rpmRuota: String, rpmPedali: String) {

        speedDisplayLabel.text = speed
        cadenceDisplayLabel.text = cadence
        distanceDisplayLabel.text = distance



    }
```

which is working.

Comment: You need to show the declaration of the function `showMeasurementWithSpeed`, but from the error, the function does not seem to accept an initial anonymous argument (`speedText`)

Comment: @Paulw11 speed text is fine. the problem is that I want to add rpm for wheel and crank to that destination infoSpeedoViewController.
so as for rpmPedaliText I copied from cadenceText it but making another variables (just a double but in Italian), I also made rpmRuotaText( for wheel rpm) just the same way but using wheel rpm data.

now the error fix it sending the swapped as I see.

Answer (score 0):

You can see quite clearly that the parameter names in your function declaration:

```
func showMeasurementWithSpeed( _ speed:String, cadence:String, distance:String, rpmRuota: String, rpmPedali: String)
```

Don't match your function invocation:

```
showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText, cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, crankRpm: rpmPedaliText, wheelRpm: rpmRuotaText)
```

You need to call it as:

```
showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText, cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, rpmRuota: rpmRuotaText, rpmPedali: rpmPedaliText)
```

Comment: Thanks it is the solution. I now see that I was using a wrong invocation by using crankRpm and wheelRpm instead of rpmPedali and rpmRuota, but also in the wrong order being the right order rpmRuota and rpmPedali.
thank you very much.

Comment: can you explain why in the invocation of the other parameters as distance: distanceText it's correct, and not distanceInMeters: distanceText ?
because that's what made use wheelRpm instead of rpmRuota.

Comment: The function signature doesn't have a parameter `distanceInMeters`, it has a parameter `distance`.  `distanceInMeters` is a named value in the tuple returned by `valuesForPreviousMeasurement`

Comment: func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double?, rpmRuota wheelRpm: Double?, rpmPedali crankRpm: Double?)

the function signature right?has distanceInMeters as rpmPedali, but

self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText, rpmRuota: rpmRuotaText, rpmPedali: rpmPedaliText)
has distance and rpmPedali

Comment: Yes?  `sensorUpdatedValues` has both public and private parameter names, so the public name is `distanceInMeters` while the private name is `distance`.  `showMeasurementWithSpeed` has only one name for each parameter.  I don't understand why you are asking about an unrelated function though; the error you are getting is simply because your function invocation doesn't match its declaration.  The declaration of `showMeasurementWithSpeed` that you have in your comment is invalid since there is no type `rpmRuotaText` or `rpmPedaliText` - note the position of the :

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use `rpmRuota rpmRuotaText: String, rpmPedali rpmPedaliText: String)` - public and private parameter names for `String` parameters

Comment: ok now I see, sorry, I wasn't seeing that the invocation is for showMeasurementWithSpeed..hence my gigantic confusion.
if you didn't wonder why I was asking for that function I would have never seen it. thank you very much again.